# How to remove blanks from Rails' simple_format() output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Rails' `simple_format()` to output addresses from my database like this:

```
<%= simple_format(@person.address) %>
```

As I result I get this markup in my Safari browser:

```
<p>
  "John Doe "<br>
  "123 Main Street "<br>
  "Eggham "<br>
  "United Kingdom"<br>
</p>
```

This is fine as long as the text appears left aligned.

When I want the text to appear *right* aligned, however, the right edge is not straight. If you look closely at the HTML, you'll see why. On all lines there are blanks at the end, except for the last one.

I don't understand where these blanks come from because I always pressed `return` immediately after entering the last letter of each line. I never entered any of these blanks, yet they appear in every address that `simple_format()` gives me.

Is there another or better way to print out a textfield in Rails without those annoying blanks at the end?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look at the String methods `.strip`, `.squeeze` and `.squish` (I never remember the differences between them but I know one of these are the one you are looking for ;)

Comment: How you @person.address look like? Can you post the string before simple_format parses it?

Comment: @MrYoshiji: Thanks. Do I need to append one of those methods to `simple_format()`? If so, it doesn't work. Just tried :-(

Comment: @MurifoX: This is what gets posted: `"address"=>"John Doe\r\n123 Main Street\r\nEggham\r\nUnited Kingdom"`

Comment: Hmmmm, the thing is, this `\r` in your code is generating the spaces. It is probably a tab or wathever. `simple_format` just outputs this too. Get rid of them and you are good to go.

Comment: @MurifoX: I created an attribute writer like this: `address.gsub("\r","")`. It doesn't change the output in any way though :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I ended up using this helper method:

```
def print_multiline(field)
  field.gsub("\r\n","<br/>").html_safe
end
```

For me this works much better than `simple_format()` because it won't create whitespace at the end of lines.

I use it in my views like this:

```
<%= print_multiline(@person.address) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

input_string.gsub("\r\n","\n") will replace Microsoft-style CR/LF with Unix-style LF characters.

Comment: I created an attribute writer like this but unfortunately it doesn't change a thing!

Comment: If you want it changed in place, use gsub!